# Most efficient portable overflow detection?

Tags: c++, c, integer, overflow, d

In close to the metal languages like C, C++ and D, what's the most efficient reasonably portable way (i.e. w/o using assembler, though you may assume two's complement arithmetic and wrap-around behavior) to detect overflow of an unsigned 64-bit integer on multiplication?

Comment: Wrap-around behaviour for unsigned types is fully specified for C and C++, and two's complement is irrelevant for such types.

Comment: @Mark:  C99 is fine.  I mostly am interested in D, but I put C and C++ in the question because any answer for them likely applies to D as well.

Comment: @dscimcha: If you had made it explicit that you wanted answers for D, and not just for any C-like language you a) would have gotten answers that you can use and b) your question wouldn't have been closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Mark:  I figured it made more sense not to turn away C/C++ answers because C and C++ are much more popular than D, and are very similar in terms of low level stuff like integers.

Answer (score 19):

You can detect overflow in advance by dividing the maximum value representable by the unsigned type by one of the multiplicands; if the result is less than the other multiplicand, then multiplying them would result in a value exceeding the range of the unsigned type.

For example, in C++ (using the C++0x exact-width numeric types):

```
std::uint64_t left = 12;
std::uint64_t right = 42;

if (left != 0 && (std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::max() / left) < right)
{
    // multiplication would exceed range of unsigned
}
```

In C, you can use `uint64_t` for the type and `UINT64_MAX` for the maximum value.  Or, if you only care that the type is *at least* 64 bits wide and not necessarily *exactly* 64 bits wide, you can use `unsigned long long` and `ULLONG_MAX`.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few answers in this [almost duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815367/multiplication-of-large-numbers-how-to-catch-overflow). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815367/multiplication-of-large-numbers-how-to-catch-overflow/1815391#1815391) should work in C, C++, and other similar languages:

```
if (b > 0 && a > 18446744073709551615 / b) {
     // overflow handling
} else {
    c = a * b;
}
```

Or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815367/multiplication-of-large-numbers-how-to-catch-overflow/1815371#1815371) which performs the multiplication and then divides the result by one of the arguments to see if it equals the other:

```
x = a * b;
if (a != 0 && x / a != b) {
    // overflow handling
}
```

Comment: Instead of 18446744073709551615 I'd use the maximum value for the used type as specified by <limits.h> macros (c) or std::numeric_limits::max (C++).

Answer (score 2):

There are probably more efficient methods but this is an easy and portable way to do it:

```
// assume 'a' and 'b' are the operands to be multiplied
if( ( a != 0 ) && ( UINT64_MAX / a ) < b ) ) {
  // overflow
}
```