# How to compare product of two variables in c++ without directly multiplying them(due to overflow)?

Tags: c++, math, overflow

**how to compute that a*b > c*d and store a value for later comparison with any other two pairs. The product is overflowed during multiplication in c++.**
`long long a = 12345678912, b=45697845821, c=47896512354, d=741258963256;`

Comment: @Ron both `a*b` and `c*d` can overflow

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid overflow in expr. A \* B - C \* D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237046/how-to-avoid-overflow-in-expr-a-b-c-d)

Comment: @jhcarl0814 appreciate for the ans.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast to float and compare a/d and c/b. Alternatively you can stay with ints and if a/d == c/b then you compare a%d and c%b.

Comment: Very nice suggestion (already upvoted). You may want to elaborate on whether special care is needed for positive and negative and 0 cases.

Comment: Yes, I assumed all numbers are strictly positive. Actually, comparing a - d and c - b should should do the trick too, and works to negative numbers and zero. Depending on the order of magnitudes, comparing (a - d) + b and c or a and (c - b) + d might be an option too.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include<boost/multiprecision/integer.hpp>
void f()
{
    long long int a_ = 12345678912;
    long long int b_ = 45697845821;
    boost::multiprecision::int128_t a(a_);
    boost::multiprecision::int128_t b(b_);
    boost::multiprecision::int128_t ab(a * b); // store a value for later comparison with any other two pairs
    bool greater_than = ab > boost::multiprecision::int128_t(47896512354) * boost::multiprecision::int128_t(741258963256);
}
```