# Verifying a test for multiplication-overflow

Tags: c++, c

I have implemented the following function for detecting whether or not a multiplication overflows:

```
bool IsSafeMul(uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
    uint32_t z = x * y;
    return (z >= x && z >= y);
}
```

I have verified it empirically, but would like to ensure that:

1. Is it 100% guaranteed to work correctly (i.e., no false-positives and no false-negatives)?
2. Is it 100% guaranteed to work correctly for any other `unsigned` type?

Comment: You can also use [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: [CERT covers how to check for overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19920014/1708801) and [clang and gcc have builtins that deal with overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32317442/1708801)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not guaranteed to work correctly. For example,

```
0x000FFFFF * 0x000FFFFF = 0xFFFFE00001
```

It produces `0xFFE00001` after truncation to 32 bits, which passes your test. But multiplication overflows.

To test for overflow on multiplication you can simply check `z / x == y` provided `x` is not zero.

Comment: Yes, that was my original implementation, which I tried to improve here. Thank you!!!