# How to multiply 2 uint8 modulo a big number without using integer type in C language

Tags: c, cryptography

If `A` and `B` are of type `uint8_t` and I want the result `C=AxB % N` where `N` is 2^16, how do i do this if I can't use integers (so I can't declare `N` as an integer, only `uint8_t`) in C language?

N.B: `A`, `B` and `C` are stored in `uint8` arrays, so they are "expressed" as `uint8` but their values can be bigger.

Comment: Why can't you use integers?

Comment: Why you can't perform calculation as `uint16_t` and then cast result back to `uint8_t`? Especially because `A*B` may be outside `uint8_t` range then...

Comment: Will the compiler promote `A` and `B`, or only if they're different types?

Comment: Is N alway 2^16 or can it be any (large) number?

Comment: You **have to** use integers. *Usual arithmetic conversions* are performed on operands, which means that `uint8_t` types are converted to `int`, whether you want it or not.

Comment: Is the number stored like this? A = 1389 -> `uint8_t A[6] = {0, 0, 1, 3, 8, 9};` ? Or is it like `uint8_t A[6] = {9, 8, 3, 1, 0, 0};` or some other way! If you want help, you need to clarify stuff like that.

Comment: Please explain *"so they are "expressed" as uint8 but their values can be bigger."*. And also provide [mcve].

Comment: What I get from you question is `A` and `B` aren't `uint8_t` at all but instead `uint8_t *`.  Right? Big difference!

Answer (score 3):

In general there is no easy way to do this.

Firstly you need to implement the multiply with carry between A and B for each uint8_t block. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815367/multiplication-of-large-numbers-how-to-catch-overflow).

Division with `2^16` really mean "disregard" the last 16 bits, "don't use" the last two `uint8_t` (as you use the array of int.). As you have the modulus operator, this means just the opposite, so you only need to get the last two `uint8_t`s.

Take the lowest two `uint8` of `A` (say `a0` and `a1`) and `B` (say `b0` and `b1`):

split each `uint8` in high and low part

```
a0h = a0 >> 4;    ## the same as a0h = a0/16;
a0l = a0 % 16;    ## the same as a0l = a0 & 0x0f;
a1h = a1 >> 4;
a1l = a1 % 16;

b0h = b0 >> 4;
b0l = b0 % 16;
b1h = b1 >> 4;
b1l = b1 % 16;
```

Multiply the lower parts first (`x` is a buffer var)

```
x = a0l * b0l;
```

The first part of the result is the last four bits of `x`, let's call it `s0l`

```
s0l = x % 16;
```

The top for bits of `x` are carry.

```
c = x>>4;
```

multiply the higher parts of first `uint8` and add carry.

```
x = (a0h * b0h) + c;
```

The first part of the result is the last four bits of `x`, let's call it `s0h`. And we need to get carry again.

```
s0h = x % 16;
c = x>>4;
```

We can now combine the `s0`:

```
s0 = (s0h << 4) +  s0l;
```

Do exactly the same for the s1 (but don't forget to add the carry!):

```
x = (a1l * b1l) + c;
s1l = x % 16;
c = x>>4;
x = (a1h * b1h) + c;
s1h = x % 16;
c = x>>4;
s1 = (s1h << 4) +  s1l;
```

Your result at this point is `c`, `s1` and `s0` (you need carry for next multiplications eg. `s2`, `s3`, `s4`,). As your formula says %(2^16) you already have your result -  `s1` and `s2`. If you have to divide with something else, you should do something similar to the code above, but for division. In this case be careful to catch the dividing with zero, it will give you `NAN` or something!

You can put A, B, C and S in array and loop it through the indexes to make code cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my effort. I took the liberty of using larger integers and pointers for looping through the arrays. The numbers are represented by arrays of `uint8_t` in big-endian order. All the intermediate results are kept in `uint8_t` variables. The code could be made more efficient if intermediate results could be stored in wider integer variables!

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void add_c(uint8_t *r, size_t len_r, uint8_t x)
{
    uint8_t o;

    while (len_r--) {
        o = r[len_r];
        r[len_r] += x;
        if (o <= r[len_r])
            break;
        x = 1;
    }
}

void multiply(uint8_t *res, size_t len_res,
        const uint8_t *a, size_t len_a, const uint8_t *b, size_t len_b)
{
    size_t ia, ib, ir;

    for (ir = 0; ir < len_res; ir++)
        res[ir] = 0;

    for (ia = 0; ia < len_a && ia < len_res; ia++) {
        uint8_t ah, al, t;

        t = a[len_a - ia - 1];
        ah = t >> 4;
        al = t & 0xf;

        for (ib = 0; ib < len_b && ia + ib < len_res; ib++) {
            uint8_t bh, bl, x, o, c0, c1;

            t = b[len_b - ib - 1];
            bh = t >> 4;
            bl = t & 0xf;

            c0 = al * bl;
            c1 = ah * bh;

            o = c0;
            t = al * bh;
            x = (t & 0xf) << 4;
            c0 += x;
            x = (t >> 4);
            c1 += x;
            if (o > c0)
                c1++;

            o = c0;
            t = ah * bl;
            x = (t & 0xf) << 4;
            c0 += x;
            x = (t >> 4);
            c1 += x;
            if (o > c0)
                c1++;

            add_c(res, len_res - ia - ib, c0);
            add_c(res, len_res - ia - ib - 1, c1);
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t a[2] = { 0xee, 0xdd };
    uint8_t b[2] = { 0xcc, 0xbb };
    uint8_t r[4];

    multiply(r, sizeof(r), a, sizeof(a), b, sizeof(b));
    printf("0x%02X%02X * 0x%02X%02X = 0x%02X%02X%02X%02X\n",
            a[0], a[1], b[0], b[1], r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0xEEDD * 0xCCBB = 0xBF06976F
```