# Why does "INT_MAX * INT_MAX" product give 1?

Tags: c, cpu-architecture, integer-overflow

I was learning computer architecture and decided to experiment with multiplication overflow. An overflow is observed for `INT_MAX * INT_MAX`, but I am not sure why this gives the product 1 in C/C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    int num = INT_MAX;
    printf("%0x\n", num);       //stdout is 0x7fffffff
    printf("%d\n", num * num);  //stdout is 1
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior.

Comment: It produces overflow which is UB

Comment: (2³¹ − 1)² = 2⁶² − 2³² + 1 ≡ 1 (mod 2³²)

Comment: What is the rationale for trying to print the square of the maximum `int` value as an `int`?

Answer (score 6):

Note: your code is invalid. Overflowing `int` * `int` is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and you *should not* write such code. The result will be unpredictable. This is a toy example where a compiler chooses to act in a specific way - but generally, the compiler is allowed to do anything with your code. If you want signed overflow to be defined, see for exmaple [Is signed overflow still undefined behaviour in gcc when -fwrapv is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54953219/is-signed-overflow-still-undefined-behaviour-in-gcc-when-fwrapv-is-used) .

---

For example, let's assume `int` on your platform has 32-bits and is [twos-complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). The result is calculated, and then truncated to 32-bits.

```
INT_MAX = 0x7fffffff = 2147483647
2147483647 * 2147483647 = 4611686014132420609
4611686014132420609     = 0x3fffffff00000001
32-bits from 0x3fffffff00000001 = 0x00000001 = 1
```

Comment: It remains astounding that people write “The result will be unpredictable” when the result is, in fact, predicted.

Comment: @EricPostpischil it is in a particular implementation. It can be different if you compile using a different compiler or target other hardware.

Comment: @EricPostpischil maybe someone computer's doesn't use twos-complement, but something else?

Comment: @EricPostpischil It’s unpredictable because it is not guaranteed by the standard. Even if all major vendors might decide to implement the result in the same way right now, there’s nothing stopping them from changing the result for the next patch

Comment: @Ranoiaetep: “Not guaranteed by the standard” is a different thing from “unpredictable.”

Comment: Most (all?) things in the world are not guaranteed, but many are predictable.

Comment: @0___________: Which simply means the prediction would rely on data such as what implementation is used.

Comment: @EricPostpischil IMO nitpick. Simply wrong wording was used. Most UBs results can be predicted assuming a particular implementation.

Comment: @0___________ It’s unpredictable from source code alone, and often cannot be reliably predicted even when given more information.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: It's *explainable*, but I wouldn't have put much money on a *prediction* for what that code would print without trying it, even if I knew it was going to be compiled by a specific compiler like GCC.  I didn't really expect GCC to treat `INT_MAX * INT_MAX` as `__builtin_unreachable()` when compiling without `-fwrapv` to make this well-defined, but it certainly could have.  And obviously any other compiler could choose differently.  `gcc -fsanitize=undefined` is also a conforming C implementation.. although it does print `1` after printing the error.

Answer (score 0):

In different machine, the size of data type "int" may be different. It may be 32 bits or 64 bits which depends on what machine you use.
The typical ranges for "int" for 32 bit programs is from -2^31(minimum) to 2^31-1(maximum). The typical ranges for "int" for 64 bit programs is from -2^63(minimum) to 2^63-1(maximum).

If your program is 32 bits, the result is (2^31-1)*(2^31-1) = 2^62-2^32+1.
Since 2^62-2^32 will only be represented in the upper 32 bits of binary result, the overflow result you will get is 1. Otherwise, if your program is 64 bits, then (2^63-1)*(2^63-1) = 2^126-2^64+1 will also lead to same result by truncating the upper 64 bits.

Comment: Your answer is assuming you compiled with `gcc -fwrapv` to make signed-integer overflow well-defined.  Otherwise, it's only by the compiler's choice that it happened to wrap / truncate, instead of doing something else.