# Is signed integer overflow undefined behaviour or implementation defined?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, implementation-defined-behavior

```
#include <limits.h>

int main(){
 int a = UINT_MAX; 
 return 0;
}
```

I this UB or  implementation defined?

**Links saying its UB**

https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.63/html_node/Integer-Overflow-Basics

[Allowing signed integer overflows in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240748/allowing-signed-integer-overflows-in-c-c)

**Links saying its Implementation defined**

http://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/INF478/docs/Cpp/en/c/language/signed_and_unsigned_integers.html

Conversion rule says:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

Aren't we converting a `max unsigned value` into a `signed value`?

The way I have seen it, gcc just truncates the result.

Comment: You have to keep straight *conversion* and *overflow in expression*.  Here the overflow occurs in *converting* `UINT_MAX` to type `int` for the assignment.  That's IDB.  When the overflow occurs in actually evaluating an expression, as in `999999999*999999999`, that's when it's UB.

Comment: I don't get the difference? here you are also converting result of `999999999*999999999` to type int which essentially truncates it.

Comment: That's not how C defines it.  Doing `999999999*999999999` is not defined as "do the mathematical operation and then perform a conversion according to the usual rules for conversion".  It's defined as "conceptually do the mathematical operation, but if the result can't be represented in type `int`, then UB".  The rules for conversion never come into play.

Comment: In case it helps in understanding, `long long int a = 999999999*999999999;` is also UB.  The UB occurs as soon as the `*` operator is evaluated.  What you try to do with the result isn't relevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both references are correct, but they do not address the same issue.

`int a = UINT_MAX;` is not an instance of signed integer overflow, this definition involves a conversion from `unsigned int` to `int` with a value that exceeds the range of type `int`. As quoted from the *École polytechnique*'s site, the C Standard defines the behavior as implementation-defined.

```
#include <limits.h>

int main(){
    int a = UINT_MAX;    // implementation defined behavior
    int b = INT_MAX + 1; // undefined behavior
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the text from the C Standard:

> **6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**
>
> 1. When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
> 2. Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.
> 3. Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

Some compilers have a command line option to change the behavior of signed arithmetic overflow from undefined behavior to implementation-defined: `gcc` and `clang` support `-fwrapv` to force integer computations to be performed modulo the 2<sup>32</sup> or 2<sup>64</sup> depending on the signed type. This prevents some useful optimisations, but also prevents some counterintuitive optimisations that may break innocent looking code. See this question for some examples: [What does -fwrapv do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47232954/what-does-fwrapv-do)

Comment: Why signed integer overflow is undefined behavior (so `if (i+1 < i)` can be optimized to `if (0)` and then removed) and not implementation-defined behavior (so the behavoir is according to hardware)?

Comment: @pmor: *signed integer overflow* is specified as having undefined behavior because the The Standard C committee decided so.  Optimizing compiler writers take advantage of this to enable various optimizations

Comment: Do you know _why_ the C committee decided so? Possibly to let compilers optimize better leading to higher performance.

Answer (score 2):

`int a = UINT_MAX;` does not overflow because no exceptional condition occurs while evaluating this declaration or the expression within it. This code is **defined** to convert `UINT_MAX` to the type `int` for the initialization of `a`, and the conversion is defined by the rules in C 2018 6.3.1.3.

Briefly, the rules that apply are:

- 6.7.9 11 says initialization behaves similarly to simple assignment: “… The initial value of the object is that of the expression (after conversion); the same type constraints and conversions as for simple assignment apply,…”
- 6.5.16.1 2 says simple assignment performs a conversion: “In *simple assignment* (`=`), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left operand.”
- 6.3.1.3 3, which covers conversion to a signed integer type when the operand value cannot be represented in the type, says: “either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.”

So, the behavior is defined.

There is a general rule in 2018 6.5 5 about exceptional conditions that occur while evaluating expressions:

> If an *exceptional condition* occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior is undefined.

However, this rule never applies in the chain above. While doing the evaluations, including the implied assignment of the initialization, we never get a result out of range of its type. The **input** to the conversion is out of range of the destination type, `int`, but the **result** of the conversion is in range, so there is no out-of-range result to trigger an exceptional condition.

(A possible exception to this is that the C implementation could, I suppose, define the result of the conversion to be out of range of `int`. I am not aware of any that do, and this is likely not what was intended by 6.3.1.3 3.)

Answer (score 1):

This in not signed integer overflow:

```
int a = UINT_MAX;
```

It is a conversion from an unsigned to a signed integer type and is *implementation defined*.  This is covered in section 6.3.1.3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding conversion of signed and unsigned integer types:

> *1* When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if the value can be represented by the new
> type, it is unchanged.
>
> *2* Otherwise,  if  the  new  type  is  unsigned,  the  value  is  converted  by  repeatedly  adding  or subtracting  one  more  than
> the  maximum  value  that  can  be  represented  in  the  new type
> until the value is in the range of the new type.6
>
> *3* **Otherwise,  the  new  type  is  signed  and  the  value  cannot  be  represented  in  it;  either  the result is implementation-defined
> or an implementation-defined signal is raised.**

An example of signed integer overflow would be:

```
int x = INT_MAX;
x = x + 1;
```

And this *is* undefined.  In fact section 3.4.3 of the C standard which defines undefined behavior states in paragraph 4:

> An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer overflow

And integer overflow only applies to signed types as per 6.2.5p9:

> The   range   of   nonnegative   values   of   a   signed   integer   type   is   a   subrange   of   the corresponding  unsigned  integer  type,  and  the  representation  of  the  same  value  in  each type  is  the  same.  **A  computation  involving  unsigned  operands  can  never  overflow,** because  a  result  that  cannot  be  represented  by  the  resulting  unsigned  integer  type  is reduced  modulo  the  number  that  is  one  greater  than  the  largest  value  that  can  be represented by the resulting type

Answer (score 0):

In the pre-existing "language" (family of dialects) the C Standard was written to describe, implementations would generally either process signed integer overflow by doing whatever the underlying platform did, truncating values to the length of the underlying type (which is what most platforms did) even on platforms which would otherwise do something else, or triggering some form of signal or diagnostic.
In K&R's book "The C Programming Language", the behavior is described as "machine-dependent".

Although the authors of the Standard have said in the published Rationale document identified some cases where they expected that implementations for commonplace platforms would behave in commonplace fashion, they didn't want to say that certain actions would have defined behavior on some platforms but not others.  Further, characterizing the behavior as "implementation-defined" would have created a problem.  Consider something like:

```
int f1(void);
int f2(int a, int b, int c);

int test(int x, int y)
{
  int test = x*y;
  if (f1())
    f2(test, x, y);
}
```

If the behavior of integer overflow were "Implementation Defined", then any implementation where it could raise a signal or have other observable side effects would be required to perform the multiplication before calling f1(), even though the result of the multiply would be ignored unless f1() returns a non-zero value.  Classifying it as "Undefined Behavior" avoids such issues.

Unfortunately, gcc interprets the classification as "Undefined Behavior" as an invitation to treat integer overflow in ways that aren't bound by ordinary laws of causality.  Given a function like:

```
unsigned mul_mod_32768(unsigned short x, unsigned short y)
{
  return (x*y) & 0x7FFFu;
}
```

an attempt to call it with `x` greater than `INT_MAX/y` may arbitrarily disrupt the behavior of surrounding code, even if the result of the function would not otherwise have been used in any observable fashion.