# what is the difference between x86_64-pc-windows-msvc and x86_64-pc-windows-gnu targets in clang

Tags: c, clang

I know that one uses libstdc++ and other use msvc standard library but what difference does it make when i compile the following without linking

```
int add(int a, int b) {return a + b;}
```

is there is any difference in the object code produced or is it the same and what is the difference between other targets

the command will be
clang -c test.c -target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/gnu

thanks

Comment: I don't know the difference, buy you can compile with [-fwrapv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47232954/what-does-fwrapv-do) to make sure they have the same behaviour on both targets.

Comment: this has nothing to do with libstdc++ because the code is only processed by the compiler. To get reliable result in all compilers you must cast to `unsigned`

Comment: Can you elaborate, @phuclv?  What are you saying should be cast, and why do you claim that's necessary for a reliable result?

Comment: @JohnBollinger that's obvious, unsigned operations never overflow and don't invoke UB

Answer (score 3):

> what is the difference between x86_64-pc-windows-msvc and x86_64-pc-windows-gnu targets in clang

The two build for different C language implementations, which in this context means standard libraries, header and library search paths, and tools (especially linker).  The former builds for the Microsoft Visual C(++), and the latter for GNU C (as provided, I believe, by MinGW and compatible toolchains).

> is there is any difference in the object code produced or is it the same

It is possible that you don't get any object code in the first place for either or both targets.  Each one requires corresponding development components to be installed on the system, which are not provided by Clang,

If both targets are in fact viable then Clang will use not just the functions of the chosen target's standard library, but also its *headers*.  Depending on the program, this could produce object code that differs in minor ways.

> and what is the difference between other targets

To the best of my knowledge, GNU C on Windows uses the same ABI (function-call conventions, data type definitions, layout rules, ...) as MSVC, so there should be no difference between the two targets in those areas. The same is not true for most other targets.  If you chose a 32-bit target or a Linux target (for example) then you could expect much larger differences, and the result might not work on the build machine.