# computing 64 bit unsigned integer multiplication and subtraction using 32 bit integers

Tags: c, unsigned-integer, bigint, extended-precision

I have a project to compute 64 bit unsigned integer addition, multiplication and subtraction using only 32 bit signed/unsigned integers in c.
The 64 bit unsigned integer is newly defined like this :

```
typedef struct {
unsigned integer hi;
unsigned integer lo;
} Integer64;
```

so 64 bit integer is just a struct that stores the upper 32 bit in high and the lower 32 bit in low.

Now I get these two Integer64 and I have to produce the multiplication and subtraction in Integer64 type as well.
In multiplication and subtraction function, I am only allowed to use Integer64 type, unsigned int type, and only integer arithmetic and logical operations.

I solved how to write addition function, but I have no clue how to do multiplication and subtraction. Can you guys help?

Comment: Have you tried using strings for storing large integers and then multiplying them?

Comment: unfortunately I am not allowed to use string types either

Comment: How do you multiply two-digit decimal numbers by each other when you have only memorized a multiplication table for one-digit numbers? Everybody is taught a way of doing that in elementary school. The same method that works in base 10 works in base 65536 or base 4294967296.

Comment: only in this case you need to find a way to store and manage the overflow.that is the problem

Comment: Use base 65536.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815367/catch-and-compute-overflow-during-multiplication-of-two-large-integers deals with multiplication of 64 bit integers with 128 bit result, but he solution is the same, just different data types.

Comment: Type/variable names can't start with a number.  Maybe call it `struct u64`.  Don't use `uint64_t`; that's already defined by ISO C as being a 64-bit integer type which is only defined by implementations that support it.  (But typically defined as either `unsigned long long` or `unsigned long`).

Comment: You can't do this efficiently on most architectures.  Most have widening multiplication of 32b x 32b => 64b, but the only way to express that in C is `a.lo * (unsigned long long)b.lo`, or with an intrinsic / built-in.  With portable C and no type wider than 32-bit, you'll have to build an extended-precision 64-bit multiply out of 16x16 => 32b chunks, like Eric said.  That probably won't optimize, so you never want to do this in practice.

Comment: It might be useful to look at how real compilers do 64x64 => 64b on a 32-bit architecture like MIPS or i386, using 1 widening multiply and 2 `lo*hi` https://godbolt.org/z/T_UzGk.  Of course this doesn't end up needing an add-with-carry (which is easy in asm but hard in C).

Comment: If you're doing this with only pure ISO C, then the [tag:cpu-architecture] tag doesn't apply.  Normally this is done in asm, because like I said it generally sucks in C, especially trying to do add-with-carry when there's a carry-in and a carry-out.