# How to write a loop that calculates power?

Tags: c++, function, loops, exponent

I'm trying to write a loop that calculates power without using the pow() function. I'm stuck on how to do that. Doing `base *= base` works for even powers upto 4, so there is something totally weird that I can't seem to figure out.

```
int Fast_Power(int base, int exp){
    int i = 2;
    int result;

    if(exp == 0){
        result = 1;
        }
    if(exp == 1){
        result = base;
        }
    else{
        for(i = 2; i < exp; i++){
            base *= base; 
            result = base;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `result = base; if (!exp) return 1; for(i = 1; i < exp; i++) result *= base; return result;` -- but you need to check for integer overflow. Even a relatively small exponent can result in overflow on a large integer...

Comment: "Doing base *= base works for even powers upto 4" --> what value of `base` was used?

Comment: @chux, powers of four work by coincidence, take `3^4` for example. You want `3*3*3*3 = 81` but you get `base` starting at 3, then squaring twice (for `i` of `2` and `3`), giving 9 then 81. Powers of two actually result in an uninitialised result.

Comment: You're not allowing for the fact that the range of values an `int` can represent is finite.   The standard doesn't guarantee that an `int` can represent more than `32767`, so a value of `base` more than `13` may cause overflow if raised to the power of `4`.   Even for a 32-bit `int`, overflow will occur if a value larger than `215` is raised to the power of `4`.    When overflow occurs of an `int`, the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

```
base *= base;
```

Your problem lies with that statement, you should not be changing `base` at all. Rather, you should be adjusting `result` based on the constant value of `base`.

To do powers, you need repeated *multiplication,* but the `base *= base` gives you a repeated *squaring* of the value and you'll therefore get a much bigger value than desired. This actually works for powers of four since you iterate `4 - 2` times, squaring each iteration, and `x4 == (x2)2`.

It will *not* work for higher powers like six since you iterate `6 - 2` times, and `x6 != (((x2)2)2)2`. That latter value is actually equivalent to `x16`.

> As an aside (despite your contention), it's actually *not* guaranteed to work for powers of two. If you follow the code in that case, you'll see that `result` is never assigned a value so the return value will be arbitrary. If it's working for you, that's accidental and likely to bite you at some point.

---

The algorithm you can use should be something like:

```
float power(float base, int exponent):
    # 0^0 is undefined.

    if base == 0 and exponent == 0:
        throw bad_input

    # Handle negative exponents.

    if exponent < 0:
        return 1 / power(base, -exponent)

    # Repeated multiplication to get power.

    float result = 1
    while exponent > 0:
        # Use checks to detect overflow.

        float oldResult = result
        result *= base
        if result / base is not close to oldResult:
            throw overflow
        exponent -= 1

    return result
```

This algorithm handles:

- negative integral exponents (since `x-y = 1/xy`);
- the undefined case of `00`; and
- overflow if you do not have arbitrary-precision values (basically, if `(x * y) / y != x`, you can be reasonably certain an overflow has occurred). Note the use of "not close to", it's unwise to check floats for exact equality due to potential for errors due to precision limits - far better to implement a "is close enough to" check of some description.

---

One thing to keep in mind when translating to C or C++, a 2's complement implementation will cause issues when using the most negative integer, since its negation is often the same value again again due to the imbalance between the positive and negative values. This is likely to lead to infinite recursion.

You can fix that simply by detecting the case early on (before anything else), with something like:

```
if INT_MIN == -INT_MAX - 1 and exp == INT_MIN:
    throw bad_input
```

The first part of that detects a 2's complement implementation, while the second detects the (problematic) use of `INT_MIN` as an exponent.

Comment: Good point, @chux, have added a note to hopefully cover that case.

Answer (score 1):

What you were doing wrong is `base *= base` each time through the loop, which changes the base itself, each iteration.

Instead you want the base to remain the same, and multiply the final result by that original base "exp" times.

```
int Fast_Power(int base, int exp){
    int result=1;

    if(exp == 0){
        result = 1;
    }
    if(exp == 1){
        result = base;
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < exp; i++){
            result *= base;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic but naive algorithm you are looking for that is horribly subject to integer overflow is:

```
int Fast_Power (int base, int exp)
{
    int result = base;

    if (exp == 0)
        return result ? 1 : 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < exp; i++) {
        result *= base;
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Note:** `result` can very easily overflow. You need to employ some basic check to prevent *integer-overflow* and *Undefined Behavior*.

A minimal check (see: [Catch and compute overflow during multiplication of two large integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815367/catch-and-compute-overflow-during-multiplication-of-two-large-integers)), can be incorporated as follows. You must use a wider-type for the temporary calculation here and then compare the results against `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` (provided in the `limits.h` header) to determine if overflow occurred:

```
#include <limits.h>
...
int Fast_Power (int base, int exp)
{
    int result = base;

    if (exp == 0)
        return result ? 1 : 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < exp; i++) {
        long long int tmp = (long long) result * base;  /* tmp of wider type */
        if (tmp < INT_MIN || INT_MAX < tmp) {           /* check for overflow */
            fputs ("error: overflow occurred.\n", stderr);
            return 0;
        }
        result = tmp;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now if you attempt, e.g.  `Fast_Power (2, 31);` an error is generated and zero returned.

Additionally as @paxdiablo notes in the comment [Zero to the power of zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero) may be undefined as there is no agreed upon value. You can add a test and issue a warning/error in that case if you desire.

Comment: Just as an aside, I believe zero to the power of zero is undefined rather than zero.

Comment: Replaced the division test for overflow with comparison against `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` as a cleaner check that avoids [C11 Standard - 3.4.3(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3p3) which is `C18 Standard - 3.4.3(p4)` (exampe text is identical in both) resulting from the intermediate `result * base` multiplication required prior to the division test.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I agree it was probably a mistake to use `base *= base`. That said, it's not necessarily the mistake. My first impression was that OP was trying to compute powers the way that a human might do by hand. For example if you wanted to compute 3^13 a reasonable way is to start is by computing exponents which are powers of 2.

- 3^1 = 3
- 3^2 = 3*3 = 9
- 3^4 = 3^2 * 3^2 = 81
- 3^8 = 3^4 * 3^4 = 6,561

Then you can use these results to compute 3^13 as

- 3^13 = 3^1 * 3^4 * 3^8 = 1,594,323

Once you understand the steps you could code this. The hardest part is probably determining when to stop squaring the base, and which squares should be included in the final calculation. Perhaps surprisingly the (unsigned) binary representation of the exponent tells us this! This is because the digits in binary represent the powers of two which sum together to form the number. With that in mind we can write the following.

```
int Fast_Power(int base, int exp) {
    int result = 1;
    unsigned int expu = exp;
    unsigned int power_of_two = 1;
    while (expu > 0) {
        if (power_of_two & expu) {
            result *= base;
            expu ^= power_of_two;
        }
        power_of_two <<= 1;
        base *= base;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This code doesn't have overflow protection, though that would be a good idea. Sticking with the original prototype it still accepts negative exponents and returns integers, which is a contradiction. Since OP didn't specify what should occur upon overflow or negative exponents this code doesn't attempt to handle either of those cases. Reasonable methods of addressing these issues are provided by other answers.