# How would it be possible to store numbers larger than 64 bit on a 64 bit architecture in C?

Tags: c

I was thinking about how someone would implement some sort of program that has to deal with very large numbers in C. If somebody were to attempt this, how would they store the number in memory? Would it be possible to have a `long *ptr` that points to a block of memory, and the addition of the values stored in that allocated memory every 8 bytes could contain the entire value? If there is some other more efficient approach, please explain, thanks!

Comment: Yes, that. [This kind of very large?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565150/biginteger-in-c)

Comment: How do you record a number larger than 9 using only digits from 0 to 9?

Comment: This is common place, there are something like `BigNum` implementations in every language to work with arbitrarily large numbers. We have been doing this since the earliest days of computing, when storing any kind of useful number typically couldn't happen in a single [word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)).

Comment: You can see some example code at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66109785) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72013383).