# How to convert very large string to number in C?

Tags: c, math, numbers

I am doing my [3x program](https://github.com/Andrej123456789/3x) and developing 3x I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66109785/handling-numbers-in-c-larger-than-ulong-max) about handling big numbers but final result is string and with string I can't do math operations. I use `gcc` compiler.

*Also this program is not meant to solve problem, I created just to test performance.*

Comment: You need to create functions that can do math using the strings - or use a library that has already solved that

Comment: Note that the approach that @Ted suggests is exactly what the answer you referenced demonstrates. Also, there are existing third-party libraries for arbitrary-precision arithmetic that are reasonably featureful.

Comment: And existing multi-precision libraries usually perform well, in addition to being feature complete.

Comment: I will try GNU GMP library

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can't. C supports integers of limited length (64 bits, about 20 digits), and floats (about 15 significant digits), not larger.

So there is no better way than using a representation in a large radix (power of 2 or power of 10) and implementing the operations based on this representation. E.g. addition can be done digit by digit, with occasional carries.

Comment: Actually I did what I wanted using GNU GMP library. Code is on GitHub if you want take a look. Thanks to everyone which contributed.