# Correctness of multiplication with overflow detection

Tags: c++, algorithm, integer-overflow, correctness, proof-of-correctness

The following C++ template [detects overflows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1815371/3410351) from multiplying two unsigned integers.

```
template<typename UInt> UInt safe_multiply(UInt a, UInt b) {
    UInt x = a * b; // x := ab mod n, for n := 2^#bits > 0
    if (a != 0 && x / a != b)
        cerr << "Overflow for " << a << " * " << b << "." << endl;
    return x;
}
```

Can you give a proof that this algorithm detects every potential overflow, regardless of how many bits `UInt` uses?

The case
[image: a=0\lor b=0]

cannot result in overflows, so we can consider
[image: a,b,n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}] .

It seems that the correctness proof boils down to leading
[image: \left\lfloor\frac{ab \mod n}{a}\right\rfloor=b~\land~ab\ge n]

to a contradiction, since `x / a` actually means [image: \left\lfloor\frac{x}{a}\right\rfloor].

When assuming
[image: \left\lfloor\frac{x}{a}\right\rfloor=\frac{x}{a}]

, this leads to the straightforward consequence
[image: \left\lfloor\frac{x}{a}\right\rfloor=b\Leftrightarrow\frac{x}{a}=b\Leftrightarrow ab \mod n=ab]

thus
[image: ab\mod n=ab\ge n]

which contradicts n > 0.

So it remains to show
[image: \left\lfloor\frac{ab \mod n}{a}\right\rfloor=\frac{ab \mod n}{a}]

or there must be another way.

If the last equation is true, WolframAlpha [fails to confirm that](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=floor%28%28a*b+mod+n%29%2Fa%29%3D%28a*b+mod+n%29%2Fa+for+a+%3E+0+and+b+%3E+0+and+n+%3E+0) (also [with exponents](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=floor%28%28a*b+mod+2%5Ek%29%2Fa%29%3D%28a*b+mod+2%5Ek%29%2Fa+for+a+%3E+0+and+b+%3E+0+and+k+%3E%3D+0)).
*However*, it asserts that the [original assumptions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+floor%28%28a*b+mod+n%29%2Fa%29%3Db+and+ab%3E%3Dn+for+a+%3E+0+and+b+%3E+0+and+n+%3E+0) have no integer solutions, so the algorithms seems to be correct indeed.
But it doesn't provide an explanation. So *why* is it correct?

I am looking for the smallest possible explanation that is still mathematically profound, ideally that it fits in a single-line comment. Maybe I am missing something trivial, or the problem is not as easy as it looks.

On a side note, I used [Codecogs Equation Editor](https://codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) for the LaTeX markup images, which apparently looks bad in dark mode, so consider [switching to light mode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/) or, if you know, please tell me how to use different images depending on the client settings. It is just `\bg{white}` vs. `\bg{black}` as part of the image URLs.

Comment: @Elliott Thanks for the notification. I will update the images to have a white background.

Comment: That last equation is definitely false, and it's false so often that you can plug in basically any random set of constants and see it fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, I'll use the multiplication and division symbols (`*`, `/`) mathematically.

Also, for convenience let's name the set `N = {0, 1, ..., n - 1}`.

Let's clear up what unsigned multiplication is:
Unsigned multiplication for some magnitude, `n`, is a modular `n` operation on unsigned-`n` inputs (inputs that are in `N`) that results in an unsigned-`n` output (ie. also in `N`).
In other words, the result of unsigned multiplication, `x`, is `x = a*b (mod n)`, and, ***additionally***, we know that `x,a,b` are in `N`.
It's important to be able to expand many modular formulas like so: `x = a*b - k*n`, where `k` is an integer - but in our case `x,a,b` are in `N` so this implies that `k` is in `N`.

Now, let's mathematically say what we're trying to prove:
Given positive integers, `a,n`, and non-negative integers `x,b`, where `x,a,b` are in `N`, and `x = a*b (mod n)`, then `a*b >= n` (overflow) implies `floor(x/a) != b`.

Proof:

If overflow (`a*b >= n`) then `x >= n - k*n = (1 - k)*n` (for `k` in `N`),
As `x < n` then `(1 - k)*n < n`, so `k > 0`.
This means `x <= a*b - n`.

So, `floor(x/a) <= floor([a*b - n]/a) = floor(a*b/a - n/a) = b - floor(n/a) <= b - 1`,
Abbreviated: `floor(x/a) <= b - 1`
Therefore `floor(x/a) != b`

Comment: Could you elaborate why `x <= a*b - n` holds in case of an overflow? This seems a crucial part that I missed.

Comment: Ah yes, so what you meant is using the definition of `mod` by which `x = a*b mod n` means there is an integer `k` such that `x = k*n + a*b` holds, and since `x < n <= a*b` we have `k <= -1`, thus `x <= a*b - n`. Your proof is correct. I will accept it if there won't be any shorter ways soon.

Answer (score -2):

The multiplication gives either the mathematically correct result, or it is off by some multiple of 2^64. Since you check for a=0, the division always gives the correct result for its input. But in the case of overflow, the input is off by 2^64 or more, so the test will fail as you hoped.

The last bit is that unsigned operations don’t have undefined behaviour except for division by zero, so your code is fine.

Comment: 1. The algorithm is not limited to 64-bit integers. 2. It is to show precisely why `x / a != b` holds whenever an overflow occured (also considering that implicit `floor()`). You gave a sketch but that's not a proof. For instance, it doesn't clarify why any two fitting numbers `a,b` multiplied modulo `n` divided by `a` cannot be floored to equal `b`.